# How to search up-down-left-right in a 1D array Java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am working on a 3x3 puzzle slider game which uses breadth first search to find the optimal solution from the initial_state to goal_state. At the moment, the gamestate method "possibleMoves()" does not search up, down, left and right. It only searched for left and right moves before I changed: 
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
into 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ ..

How can I adjust my current code to perform the correct searches?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameState {
    final char[] board;
    private int spacePos;
    static final char[] INITIAL_BOARD = { '2', '3', '5', '4', '6', '8', '7', '1', ' ' };
    static final char[] GOAL_BOARD = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', ' ' };

    /*
     * GameState is a constructor that takes a char array holding a board
     * configuration as argument.
     */
    public GameState(char[] board) {
        this.board = board;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (board[j] == ' ') {
                this.spacePos = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * clone returns a new GameState with the same board configuration as the
     * current GameState.
     */
    public GameState clone() {
        char[] clonedBoard = new char[9];
        System.arraycopy(this.board, 0, clonedBoard, 0, 9);
        return new GameState(clonedBoard);
    }

    public int getSpacePos() {
        return spacePos;
    }

    /*
     * toString returns the board configuration of the current GameState as a
     * printable string.
     */
    public String toString() {
        String s = "[";
        for (char c : this.board)
            s = s + c;
        return s + "]";
    }

    /*
     * isGoal returns true if and only if the board configuration of the current
     * GameState is the goal configuration.
     */
    public boolean isGoal() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (this.board[j] != GOAL_BOARD[j])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * sameBoard returns true if and only if the GameState supplied as argument has
     * the same board configuration as the current GameState.
     */
    public boolean sameBoard(GameState gs) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (this.board[j] != gs.board[j])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * possibleMoves returns a list of all GameStates that can be reached in a
     * single move from the current GameState.
     */
    public ArrayList<GameState> possibleMoves() {
        ArrayList<GameState> moves = new ArrayList<GameState>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i != this.spacePos) {
                int distance = Math.abs(this.spacePos - i);
                if (distance <= 3) {
                    GameState newState = this.clone();
                    newState.board[this.spacePos] = this.board[i];
                    newState.board[i] = ' ';
                    newState.spacePos = i;
                    moves.add(newState);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        return moves;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the puzzle slider has only 1 open space, the way you are doing possibleMoves is not the right way. You should create moveFromTheLeft, moveFromTheRight, moveFromTheTop, moveFromTheBottom and add the boards created from calling these four methods to your queue

Comment: Hi, how would I go about implementing these methods and adding them to my possiblemoves method? This is also something I am stuck on as it was my initial idea @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 0):

To determine if you can move up, down, left, and right for a 3x3 game board, you would want to add the following methods:

```
// The space directly above, if it is not in the first row
// Is i - 3
boolean canGoUp(i) {
  return (i - 3 >= 0) ? true : false;
}

// The space directly below, if it is not in the last row
// Is i + 3
boolean canGoDown(i) {
  return (i + 3 < 9) ? true : false;
}

// The space to the left, if not in the first column
// Is i - 1
boolean canGoLeft(i) {
  return (i % 3 != 0) ? true : false;
}

// The space to the right, if not in the last column
// Is i + 1
boolean canGoRight(i) {
  return ((i + 1) % 3 != 0) ? true : false;
}
```

For a more general NxN game board, you can just replace the 3 and 9 in the formulas with N and N*N respectively.

Comment: Is this python? I'm not sure how to implement this into the gameState class.

Comment: No, it's java. It's just a different way of writing if-else-statements. It's on the form `statement` ? `then this` : `else this`.

Comment: I mean how would I implement this into my possibleMoves() method? Do I just delete the method or?

Comment: You first need to add these four methods to your class.  Then inside your possibleMoves method, you can call all four methods and the ones that return true you can add the correct index for the direction (the comment just before each of the methods).  Edited because you dont actually need the for-loop if your current index is a field in your class

Comment: Could you guide a newbie a little more on how to go about doing this? @austin